# Trying to divide the columns and it's returning error division by zero in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, mysql-error-1064, snowflake-schema

I have sql query which will calculate the cumulative sum and etc. Below is the query

```
SELECT 
  GRP,  
  category, 
  price, 
  units, 
  CASE WHEN customers > 10 THEN customers ELSE 0 END AS customers_adj,
  1.00000 *(
    SUM(customers_adj) OVER(PARTITION BY grp, category ORDER BY 
        FIGURE DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ))/ SUM(customers_adj) OVER (PARTITION BY grp, category) AS cum_max_price_cust
FROM 
  table_1
```

The issue is with the last column. It's returning error as SQL Error [100051] [22012]: Division by zero. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: is there any row where sum(customers_adj) OVER (partition by grp, category) = 0?

Comment: 1.00000 *(
    SUM(customers_adj) OVER(PARTITION BY grp, category ORDER BY 
        FIGURE DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    )) contains some 0's

Comment: So what do you want to happen when the value is zero?

Comment: Just create a case when construct: SELECT...CASE yourValueThatCouldBeZero WHEN 0 THEN valueIfItsZero ELSE something/yourValueThatCouldBeZero  END...

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
Select dividend / NULLIF(divisor, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DIV0. It returns 0 when the divisor is 0 (rather than reporting an error).

```
SELECT 
  GRP,  
  category, 
  price, 
  units, 
  CASE WHEN customers > 10 THEN customers ELSE 0 END AS customers_adj,
  1.00000 * DIV0( (
    SUM(customers_adj) OVER(PARTITION BY grp, category ORDER BY 
        FIGURE DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    )), SUM(customers_adj) OVER (PARTITION BY grp, category) ) AS cum_max_price_cust
FROM 
  table_1;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/div0.html